# Run function on click and page load?

Tags: jquery

I have checkboxes within labels. I need the label to have a class when the checkbox is checked, but not when it doesn't. I manged it with this:

```
  $('label').click(function(){
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]', this).is(':checked')) {
     $(this).addClass('checked');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('checked');
    }
  });
```

However when the page loads, if a checkbox is checked the label doesnt have the class, as the code hasnt been run yet.

Id like to put the code in a function and call it however the following isnt working. Both my code examples are wrapped in dom ready.

```
  function checkFunc(){
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
      $(this).parent('label').addClass('checked');
    } else {
      $(this).parent('label').removeClass('checked');
    }
  }

  checkFunc();
  $('label').click(checkFunc);
```

Have I got a syntax error or is something fundamentally wrong with my code?

UPDATE Ive tried the following:

```
  function checkFunc(){
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]', this).is(':checked')) { 
      $(this).parent('label').addClass('checked');
    } else {
      $(this).parent('label', this).removeClass('checked');
    }
  }

  $('label').each(checkFunc).click(checkFunc);
```

Comment: When you call the function with `checkFunc()` then `this` refers to `window`, not a `label` element.

Comment: You could pass `this` into the function as a parameter ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the function with `checkFunc()` then `[this` refers to `window`][1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), not a `label` element.

It looks like you want to run the function on each label element, so use `.each` instead:

```
$('label')
  .each(checkFunc)
  .click(checkFunc);
```

But you could also simply rigger the click event handler after you bound it, instead of creating a named function:

```
$('label').click(function(){
   // ...
}).triggerHandler('click');
```

Comment: Ive attempted to implement your code, see my update to my question.

Comment: Uh, well, you should use the first implementation of your function, not the second one. `$(this).parent('label')` is incorrect because `this` is already the `label` element.